# How to import and query 4-column N-Quad quadruples into Blazegraph?

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases, triplestore, blazegraph

I'm relatively new to RDF/SPARQL and I'm trying to import and query some N-Quad, 4 column/quadruple data, into [Blazegraph](https://www.blazegraph.com) (See [schemaOrgEvent.sample.txt](http://data.dws.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/structureddata/2015-11/quads/classspecific/schemaOrgEvent.sample.txt)).

When I import the Quads data (web console), I'm left with only triples-based 3-column tuple data, i.e. Blazegraph is allowing only SPARQL queries SELECTing {?s ?p ?o},but quadruple selections {?s ?p ?o ?c}, do not. **What am I doing wrong???**

**Can Blazegraph store 4-column Quad data, natively, or am I mis-understanding the nature of RDF/Triple/Quad storage?**

- My [Blazegraph](https://www.blazegraph.com) schema/knowledge database (to import into), ***is*** configured for QUADs with:
  `com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=true`
- I've imported the [Quads-file](http://data.dws.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/structureddata/2015-11/quads/classspecific/schemaOrgEvent.sample.txt) into [Blazegraph](https://www.blazegraph.com) using the web-based UPDATE console @ http://127.0.0.1:9999/bigdata/#update. I ***haven't*** tried direct [bulk upload](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/REST_API#Bulk_Data_Load) yet.

Also, the imported quad data, as well as becoming triples (normalised???),  appears to have column 1 converted to another, Blazegraph-provided (?), identifier, the original (Quad) data format being (4-columns)

```
_:node03f536f724c9d62eb9acac3ef91faa9 <http://schema.org/PostalAddress/addressRegion> "Kentucky"@en <http://concerts.eventful.com/Lauren-Alaina> .
```

And after import (3-columns):

```
t1702   schema:PostalAddress/addressRegion  Kentucky
```

Whose query was:

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
    ?s ?p ?o
    #?s ?p ?o ?c - Won't work :-(
    FILTER(STR(?o)="Kentucky")
}
```

The value 't1702' is a 'foreign key' of sorts and can be used to link to other triples (i.e. it is repeated within the imported date).

Answer (score 7):

SPARQL queries RDF triples.  The fourth dimension of a Quad data store is the graph.  RDF can be divided into separate graphs of triples, analogous to tables in a database.  You may be able to query the Quad store with the following:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
   GRAPH ?g {
      ?s ?p ?o
   }
}
```